# Regex паттерн предложения

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо найти в тексте предложение в одинарных кавычках, которые могут содержать знаки препинания и числа. Перед закрывающей кавычкой стоит один из трех символов . ? ! 
Ввод:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 'Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 45 nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut, aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.' Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Вывод:

> 'Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 45 nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut, aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'

Мой код (игнорирует запятые):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\'[\w\s]+[.!?]?\'");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(text);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

Comment: а чем именно ваш код вам не подходит?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц предложение с запятыми взять не получается.

Comment: `var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"'[^']*[?!.]'").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Regex regex = new Regex(@"\'[\w\s]+[.!?]?\'");
> ```

```
Regex regex = new Regex("'.*?[.?!]'");
```

Comment: А так, чтобы он не брал все подряд?

Comment: и опять ни строчки пояснений. может, всё-таки стоит их добавить?

Comment: @Gendalf, а если заменить точку на `[^']`?